# Samsung Galaxy S3 suddenly dies and won't turn on even after battery removal

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot, shutdown

The phone was plugged in to my computer (I was doing development) and was running all the time. Suddenly, while I was not doing development or doing anything, the phone died and I have have never been able to turn it on again.

I've tried:

- Hold the Power button
- Hold both Power and Volume down button
- Take out the battery and put it in again
- Replace the batter with another one from my friends' working-perfectly-fine Galaxy S3

The result is the same: no response from the phone at all - it's completely cold, no sound, light or vibration at all - all I've seen is the blank unchanged screen so please don't ask me about the start up screen

What can I do?

Comment: what happens if you plug it in with a charger?

Comment: Nothing, absolutely nothing at all @geffchang T_T (no light, nothing on the screen whatsoever)

Comment: Leave the battery out, (btw, check the battery to make sure its looking ok and not lumpy - if is, do *not* use it!) Leave device battery cover open, and unplugged, wait for a bit for the current residual voltage to dissipate eventually, give it an hour at least, then put battery back in, if no sign of life, then either charging unit is fried or motherboard fried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out through searches that this is the Sudden Death Syndrome (SDS) which many have reported especially for Samsung Galaxy S3.

It was the motherboard that was broken and replacing it brought the phone back to life.

Comment: so its hardware issue?????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Yes, it is a hardware issue

Answer (score 0):

Plug the phone back into the PC. Then use windows explorer and verify that your PC can see it. This will tell you if the phone is recoverable. If you can access everything within the phone, then it might be a dead screen.

Comment: If the phone doesn't make the startup sound or flash the notification LED, it's definitely not just the screen.

Comment: @DanHulme you are completely right :D